# Can we compute the joint distribution given the marginal distribution (and other informations)?

Tags: distributions, correlation, multivariate-analysis, density-function, joint-distribution

I have only studied the very basics of statistics, but I always wondered ever since I first studied the joint distribution of two random variables if it's possible to get the joint distribution from the marginal distributions, given some information about the distribution. More precisely I mean a necessary condition.

I guess one could find it given the moments of the distribution (I assume this might not always be true, but I don't have enough knowledge on the topic) but it feels like that's "too much".

The question still stands, given the marginal distributions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, what information do you need to find the joint distribution $f(x,y)$?

Comment: The information is equivalent to a [copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula), but there are very many ways to supply it and to estimate it.  Would you perhaps have a specific application in mind where we could give a less general answer?

Comment: I guess the most direct application would be what kind of joint distributions you can get from marginal normal distributions. I know the covariance is not enough (unless you also assume the type of the distribution, such as a binormal), but do you need a function or infinite series of parameters?

Comment: Yes: that's what the theory of copulas shows you.  [Here is a useful site search.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+copula+answers%3A1)

Comment: Sklar's theorem (which I found Wikipedia's page for Copula) seems to prove exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.